# Complex coefficient in Fourier series

Tags: complex-numbers, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Why can $$\sum_{n=1}^N a_n \frac{e^{2 \pi i n t} + e^{-2 \pi i n t}}{2} + b_n \frac{e^{2 \pi i n t} - e^{-2 \pi i n t}}{2i} $$
be written as
$$ \sum_{n=-N}^N c_n e^{2 \pi i n t}$$
for some setting of the coefficients $c_n$?

My complex math is a bit rusty, and I'm having trouble seeing how the $c_n$s should be set. I know that we will somehow end up with $c_{-n} = \overline{c_n}$. I have tried breaking it down to $sin$s and $cos$, but that seems to be going in the opposite direction.

Comment: $e^{2in\pi}(\frac{a_n+b_n}{2})+e^{-2in\pi}(\frac{a_n-b_n}{2})\\c_n=(\frac{a_n+b_n}{2})\\n \to -n' \to e^{-(-2in'\pi)}(\frac{a_{-n'}-b_{-n'}}{2})\to\\n'=-1,-2,-3,... \to e^{2in'\pi}(\frac{a'_{n'}-b'_{n'}}{2})\to c'_n=(\frac{a'_{n'}-b'_{n'}}{2}) $

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with your arrow notation. Can you please elaborate?